# Copying Intellisense member list drop-down to the clipboard?

Tags: intellisense, clipboard

Is there any way or plugin to copy the member drop-down list of methods in a class within Visual Studio 2008 from intellisense to the clipboard?

I'm doing some documenting of existing code and I'd like to have a quick list of all the methods and their signatures that appear in the member drop down within VS copied to the clipboard so I can paste into my documentation.

I've done some quick searches here already and couldn't find anything similar so if I've overlooked an existing question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of.  You might like to try a documentation generator like [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) to do the work for you.